# How do you find the mean proximity of two clusters using Manhattan Distance way or the Euclidean Distance way?

Tags: clustering

Question

[image]

Solution
[image]

I don't understand how the mean proximity is calculated here like it says take the average of the $x$ components then add it with the average of the $y$ components of these $16$ distances. From my understanding I thought it was like taking all the values of the $x$ coordinates and getting their average and then doing the same for the $y$ coordinates and then finally adding them together but that's not the case. In general, how does one compute the mean proximity of $2$ clusters using the Manhattan Distance?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I honestly just don't get how it works. Like I'm not familiar with the mean proximity and that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 1):

That’s a terrible text you have there; it’s full of grammatical mistakes and it adds the distances in a different order than it listed them before. If I were you I’d switch to a different text and/or course if at all possible.

The mean distance between the clusters is the distance averaged over all pairs. For the Manhattan distance, this is

\begin{eqnarray}
|A-B|&=&\frac1{16}\sum_{ij}|a_i-b_j|
\\
&=&
\frac1{16}\sum_{ij}\left(|a_{i1}-b_{j1}|+|a_{i2}-b_{j2}|\right)\;.
\end{eqnarray}

The solution you quote computes this as

$$
\frac1{16}\sum_{ij}|a_{i1}-b_{j1}|+\frac1{16}\sum_{ij}|a_{i2}-b_{j2}|\;.
$$

It’s unnecessarily hard to understand because of the change in order. For instance, $|a_{11}-b_{41}|=5$, $|a_{21}-b_{41}|=5$ , $|a_{31}-b_{41}|=7$, $|a_{41}-b_{41}|=7$, which yields the first term in the solution.

Comment: Sorry but a11 means like the first point (1,1) on cluster A and b41 means point (-4,-1) on cluster B?

Comment: @LorenBeer: No, those are $a_1$ and $b_4$, respectively. The second index $1$ refers to the first coordinate, so $a_{11}=1$ and $b_{41}=-4$.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much, this was really helpful btw!!